# codeigniter chat box is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, chat

I am making a chat box in codeigniter, but after enter the name and message, pop up box is coming showing 'Forbidden'.

I am really confused what I put instead shout.php here(chatbox.php')
 $.post('shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {

instead of 'shout.php' I put http://localhost/myfoldername/application/views/shout.php

my controller
money_c

```
function chat(){

    $this->load->view('chatbox');
}
```

chatbox.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Chat Box</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.shout_box {
    background: #627BAE;
    width: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20%;
    z-index:9;
}
.shout_box .header .close_btn {
    background: url(images/close_btn.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
.shout_box .header .close_btn:hover {
    background: url(images/close_btn.png) no-repeat 0px -16px;
}

.shout_box .header .open_btn {
    background: url(images/close_btn.png) no-repeat 0px -32px;
    float: right;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
.shout_box .header .open_btn:hover {
    background: url(images/close_btn.png) no-repeat 0px -48px;
}
.shout_box .header{
    padding: 5px 3px 5px 5px;
    font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 39, 121, .76);
    border-bottom:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.shout_box .header:hover{
    background-color: #627BAE;
}
.shout_box .message_box {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.shout_msg{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    color:#7C7C7C;
}
.message_box:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
time{
    font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    float:right;
    color: #D5D5D5;
}
.shout_msg .username{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.user_info input {
    width: 98%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
    font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
.shout_msg .username{
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // load messages every 1000 milliseconds from server.
    load_data = {'fetch':1};
    window.setInterval(function(){
     $.post('shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {
        $('.message_box').html(data);
        var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
     });
    }, 1000);

    //method to trigger when user hits enter key
    $("#shout_message").keypress(function(evt) {
        if(evt.which == 13) {
                var iusername = $('#shout_username').val();
                var imessage = $('#shout_message').val();
                post_data = {'username':iusername, 'message':imessage};

                //send data to "shout.php" using jQuery $.post()
                $.post('shout.php', post_data, function(data) {

                    //append data into messagebox with jQuery fade effect!
                    $(data).hide().appendTo('.message_box').fadeIn();

                    //keep scrolled to bottom of chat!
                    var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
                    $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);

                    //reset value of message box
                    $('#shout_message').val('');

                }).fail(function(err) { 

                //alert HTTP server error
                alert(err.statusText); 
                });
            }
    });

    //toggle hide/show shout box
    $(".close_btn").click(function (e) {
        //get CSS display state of .toggle_chat element
        var toggleState = $('.toggle_chat').css('display');

        //toggle show/hide chat box
        $('.toggle_chat').slideToggle();

        //use toggleState var to change close/open icon image
        if(toggleState == 'block')
        {
            $(".header div").attr('class', 'open_btn');
        }else{
            $(".header div").attr('class', 'close_btn');
        }


    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="shout_box">
<div class="header">chat box<div class="close_btn">&nbsp;</div></div>
  <div class="toggle_chat">
  <div class="message_box">
    </div>
    <div class="user_info">
    <input name="shout_username" id="shout_username" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="15" />
   <input name="shout_message" id="shout_message" type="text" placeholder="Type Message Hit Enter" maxlength="100" /> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

shout.php

```
<?php
####### db config ##########
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'money1';
$db_host = 'localhost';
####### db config end ##########

if($_POST)
{
    //connect to mysql db
    $sql_con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('could not connect to database');

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    } 

    if(isset($_POST["message"]) &&  strlen($_POST["message"])>0)
    {
        //sanitize user name and message received from chat box
        //You can replace username with registerd username, if only registered users are allowed.
        $username = filter_var(trim($_POST["username"]),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
        $message = filter_var(trim($_POST["message"]),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
        $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


        //insert new message in db
        if(mysqli_query($sql_con,"INSERT INTO shout_box(user, message, ip_address) value('$username','$message','$user_ip')"))
        {
            $msg_time = date('h:i A M d',time()); // current time
            echo '<div class="shout_msg"><time>'.$msg_time.'</time><span class="username">'.$username.'</span><span class="message">'.$message.'</span></div>';
        }

        // delete all records except last 10, if you don't want to grow your db size!
        mysqli_query($sql_con,"DELETE FROM shout_box WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM shout_box ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10) as sb)");
    }
    elseif($_POST["fetch"]==1)
    {
        $results = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT user, message, date_time FROM (select * from shout_box ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) shout_box ORDER BY shout_box.id ASC");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            $msg_time = date('h:i A M d',strtotime($row["date_time"])); //message posted time
            echo '<div class="shout_msg"><time>'.$msg_time.'</time><span class="username">'.$row["user"].'</span> <span class="message">'.$row["message"].'</span></div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Are you kiddin me?');
        exit();
    }
}
```

but after entering name and message alert box will pop up showing 'Forbidden'.

Comment: I think the problem is with this line: $.post('shout.php', load_data,  function(data). The URL 'shout.php' is local so it will attempt to load it from whatever folder it is currently in. Make sure you can access the shout.php page yourself using your browser and put that URL here.

Comment: @manju. the post action must be to a `controller`, where is your `shout.php` is located?

Comment: @Christian http://localhost/myfoldername/application/views/shout.php . is it correct

Comment: @AStro shout.php is located inside views

Comment: http://localhost/myfoldername/application/views/shout.php is not how it should be can not access views like that in url views should be loaded on to controller `$this->load->view('shout');`

Comment: how will i write url please guide.chatbox.php and shout.php are inside view

Comment: I think shout.php should be loaded as a function on a controller.

Comment: function chat() {

    $this->load->view('chatbox');   $this->load->view('shout');
} is it correct

Comment: still pop up coming 'Forbidden'

Comment: As i said the file shout.php looks more like should be a function on controller it does not look like a view.

Comment: @manju just move `shout.php` file to `controller`..then it will work and also add `echo json_encode('data you want to get at jquery scripts')`

Comment: i moved shout.php to controller,but what will i write instead of shout.php, insdie chatbox.php still pop up showing 'Not found'

Comment: @manju codeigniter follows MVC architecture. So first write your code in a mvc pattern after that you will get an idea

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you fully grasp MVC architecture and this is not really the place to explain it.

I suggest you study it more but what may work for you here is to modify your controller function to this:

```
function chat(){
    $this->load->view('chatbox');    
}

function shout(){
    $this->load->view('shout');
}
```

You would then need to ensure that the URL(route) works.

Assume you current URL is www.mysite.com/someController/chat/

then the new URL would be www.mysite.com/someController/shout/

If this URL does not work then you would need to sort out your route to make it work.

If this URL works, then you need to update your JQuery URL from

```
.post('shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {
```

to

```
.post('/someController/shout/', load_data,  function(data) {
```

TL;DR
The jquery post function accesses the fule via the URL like a real person. It cannot load the file directly.